# Is there design mode for Qt Creator?

Tags: python, qt-designer

I 'm making a widget for Qt Designer with Python.
My problem is how to **prevent some code running when the widget is in Qt Designer** and run only when the application runs.
Is there something like qtdesigner.designerMode?

Comment: I'm sorry I'm having trouble understanding exactly what you are asking.  Do you want to prevent your python program from running if it is using a widget that was created in Qt Designer and is currently open in Qt Designer?

Comment: Are you sure your model and view are well separated? I don't think this should be necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I wasn't clear enough: I want the code in my widget 's init function, to be able to check if it's in design mode (that is in Qt Designer) or in run mode (when the application runs).
Finally I found it and it is:

```
QtGui.qApp.applicationName()
```

If returns "python", it's in run mode.

If returns "Designer", it's in design mode.

Answer (score 0):

You could pass the information inside the qt designer plugin. For example like this:

```
class MyCustomWidget(self):
    def __init__(self, parent, qt_designer=False):
        if self._qt_designer:
            # only while inside qt designer
        # do init

class MyPlugin(QPyDesignerCustomWidgetPlugin):
    def createWidget(self, parent):
        return MyCustomWidget(parent, qt_designer=True)
```

or if you don't like to add another argument to `__init__` you could do something like:

```
class MyCustomWidget(self):
    _qt_designer = False
    def __init__(self, parent):
        if self._qt_designer:
            # only while inside qt designer
        # do init

class MyPlugin(QPyDesignerCustomWidgetPlugin):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        MyCustomWidget._qt_designer = True # set class variable

    def createWidget(self, parent):
        return MyCustomWidget(parent)
```